# JPA Criteria join

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, entity, criteria

I have two entity classes with many to one relation. I need to select all the parent records that has a child record with a min value smaller than provided.

`@Entity 

class Parent; { 

String source; 

}`

@Entity 
class child { 
@ManyToOne Parent parent; 
int value; 
}

What I need is to select all the Parent classes where Parent.source = X and min(Child.value> < Y. How to add the join on the parent/child entity and the specific select criteria?

`CriteriaBuilder cb = context.em().getCriteriaBuilder(); 

CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Parent.class); 

Root r = cq.from(Parent.class); 

Predicate p = cb.conjunction(); 

p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(r.get("source"), X)); 

Expression y = cb.literal(Y); 

// what to do with y? 

cq.where(p); 

TypedQuery tq = context.em().createQuery(cq); 

tq.setFirstResult(0); 

tq.setMaxResults(100); 

return tq.getResultList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be easier if the parent has a child OneToMany back.  But with your current model it should be something like,

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = context.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root r = cq.from(Parent.class);
Root child = cq.from(Child.class);
Predicate p = cb.and(cb.equal(r.get("source"), X), cb.equal(child.get("parent"), r));
Predicate p = cb.and(p, cb.lt(child.get("value"), Y)));
cq.where(p);
TypedQuery tq = context.em().createQuery(cq);
tq.setFirstResult(0);
tq.setMaxResults(100);
return tq.getResultList();
```

That would be any child has a value less than the value.  For all of, you would need to do a sub query.

Comment: great! so the "join" is done by the child -> parent AND. Thanks a lot!